# angular api not executed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component to display the details of ExerciseFramework object, so in the ngOnInit i call an api that returns the ExerciseFramework object to display it, and i have a form in this component to update a part of this object. I have the saveJoinability function that updates and call again the api that returns the ExerciseFramework object to refresh the data that will be displayed. But that api is not executed

```
  public exerciseFramework$: Observable<models.ExerciseFramework>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exerciseFramework$ = this.apiExerciseFramework.findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET({ externalId: this.externalId });
  }

  public saveJoinability(event: SendData): void {
    this.apiExerciseFramework.updateJoinabilityUsingPATCH({ updateJoinabilityRequest: this.args }).pipe(takeUntil(this.updateDestroyed$)).subscribe();
    this.exerciseFramework$ = this.apiExerciseFramework.findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET({ externalId: this.externalId }); // is not executed
  }

  <ng-container *ngIf="(exerciseFramework$ | async) as exerciseFramework">

  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Is the function `saveJoinability()` executed?

Comment: @MichaelD, yes, updateJoinabilityUsingPATCH function executed, but findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET no

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `subscribe`.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.exerciseFramework$ = this.apiExerciseFramework.findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET({ externalId: this.externalId }).subscribe();
  }

  public saveJoinability(event: SendData): void {
    this.apiExerciseFramework.updateJoinabilityUsingPATCH({ updateJoinabilityRequest: this.args }).pipe(takeUntil(this.updateDestroyed$)).subscribe();
    this.exerciseFramework$ = this.apiExerciseFramework.findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET({ externalId: this.externalId }).subscribe(); // is not executed
  }
```

Comment: i get this error: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ExerciseFramework>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Comment: Can you post the source code of `findExerciseFrameworkUsingGET`?